# vscode remote container failed . because Failed to download VS Code Server and HTTP 407 - Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: visual-studio-code

[vscode remote container failed]  because Failed to download VS Code Server  and HTTP 407 - Proxy Authentication Required

logs as below

```
[4 ms] Remote-Containers 0.163.0 in VS Code 1.54.1 (f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8).
[81 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[84 ms] Setting up container: /beautiful_leakey
[88 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container /beautiful_leakey
[152 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[152 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[222 ms] Server API version: 1.40
[223 ms] Start: Inspecting container
[223 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type container 7ae9aff5ec5921df298a7e47504241bc93f4906d37849b9aa915da8c47a4c12d
[292 ms] Start: Run: docker exec -i -u root -e VSCODE_REMOTE_CONTAINERS_SESSION=541b98c3-3bff-463f-9e0f-ea4e6a5e4ee01614950083609 7ae9aff5ec5921df298a7e47504241bc93f4906d37849b9aa915da8c47a4c12d /bin/sh
[297 ms] Start: Run in container: uname -m
[414 ms] x86_64
[414 ms] Start: Run in container: (cat /etc/os-release || cat /usr/lib/os-release) 2>/dev/null
[416 ms] PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
[416 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /etc/passwd
[419 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server
[421 ms] Start: Run in container: set -o noclobber ; mkdir -p '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine' && { > '/root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/.writeMachineSettingsMarker' ; } 2> /dev/null
[423 ms] Exit code 2
[423 ms] Start: Run in container: cat /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json
[425 ms] cat: /root/.vscode-server/data/Machine/settings.json: No such file or directory
[425 ms] Exit code 1
[425 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /root/.vscode-server/bin/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8
[426 ms] Exit code 1
[426 ms] Start: Run in container: test -d /vscode/vscode-server/bin/x64/f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8
[427 ms] Exit code 1
[428 ms] Installing VS Code Server for commit f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8
[428 ms] Start: Downloading VS Code Server
[494 ms] Failed to download VS Code Server (https://update.code.visualstudio.com/commit:f30a9b73e8ffc278e71575118b6bf568f04587c8/server-linux-x64/stable): HTTP 407 - Proxy Authentication Required
```

can anybody help me?